# Azure App Service Deployment Slot Deployment Center Deployment Failing

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy to a deployment slot of Azure App Service through the deployment center. I have a repo in Azure DevOps and using Kudu deployment. On the last step when I click on Finish the deployment set up through Azure Portal, I am getting the following error -

> Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.WebHostingException: AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client:

Now, it is stuck on

> Fetching deployment data ...

How to fix this issue?

Comment: As far as I know, this error is usually caused by the fact that you did not encode the thumbprint correctly. After you obtain the thumbprint, please check your code to ensure that it is properly Base64 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says that the key for authentication wasn't found by the system. Even if it does found the key for authentication it isn't correct. So that might be a reason because you might have added the wrong key path or wrong password. Please check it and double-check if that is correct or not.